# Accessing route parameters in Dart and flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am sending 2 parameters **restaurantDetails.rest_latitude** and **restaurantDetails.rest_longitude** to a class to get the map details

```
BarMapWidget(restaurantDetails.rest_latitude, restaurantDetails.rest_longitude),
```

In the class I have a stateful widget

```
class BarMapWidget extends StatefulWidget {

  String restLatitude;
  String restLongitude;

  BarMapWidget(this.restLatitude, this.restLongitude, {Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override

  _BarMapWidgetState createState() => _BarMapWidgetState();

}
```

I am passing a string so I know I have to make it a double

Here is the extended class,

```
class _BarMapWidgetState extends State<BarMapWidget> {


// Destination Longitude
final double _destLatitude = restLatitude;
final double _destLongitude = restLongitude;

void initState() {
    // Add destination marker

    _addMarker(
      LatLng(_destLatitude, _destLongitude),
      "destination",
      // BitmapDescriptor.defaultMarkerWithHue(90),
      BitmapDescriptor.defaultMarker
    );
    super.initState();
  }
```

Which give me a  Undefined name 'restLatitude'. and Undefined name 'restLongitude'.

How can I access the variable in BarMapWidget?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `restLatitude` and `restLongitude` on widget level, try using `widget.variableName`. Also, those aren't matching datatype.

If you need `double` convert `BarMapWidget` variable to double.

To initialize on state level you can trick with using `late` or use `initState`;

```dart
class BarMapWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  final double restLatitude;
  final double restLongitude;

  const BarMapWidget(this.restLatitude, this.restLongitude, {Key? key})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  _BarMapWidgetState createState() => _BarMapWidgetState();
}

class _BarMapWidgetState extends State<BarMapWidget> {
// Destination Longitude
  late final double _destLatitude = widget.restLatitude;
  late final double _destLongitude = widget.restLongitude;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that's solves that, I wasn't aware of the widget. option.  And  now I have also converted to double, myMarkers stopped working but that's an other issue. thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Just add in

```
widget.restLatitude
```

Comment: Please review the accepted answer for a good example of the level of detail and explanation expected of useful answers on Stack Overflow.